# What would happen if all escape paths of Dementors are blocked by Patronus Charm?

Tags: harry-potter, dementors

When Patronus Charm is spelled, Dementors escape. Its possible that many wizards could cast that spell from all directions to block all escape paths of Dementors. What would happen then?

Would Dementors vanish to null void? Or, something else?

Comment: Is it possible that they, bearing or not bearing the pain, turn into something else or die?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Patronus is defined (by Prof. Lupin, in the third **book**), as a shield made of positive thoughts and memories. The Dementor would feed off of the Patronus in place of the user.

In the movie, it was seen that Dementors run away from Patronuses, or that they are hurt by it. That's not the same in the books.

So if a Dementor is "trapped" inside of a Patronus prison, he'd simply have more to feed on it.

Comment: Would anyone have guessed that beside Ninjutsu, Madara is also a master at Witchcraft and Wizardry? :)

Comment: @JNat: Puny mortal, I am a ***GOD***, you thought that Ninjutsu was the only thing I knew?!

Comment: They are hurt by the patronus; Harry's Patronus makes the dementors receed in Prisoner of Azkaban and the Order of the Phoenix; moreover Prof. Lupin had told Harry during his patronus conjuring trainings that a true patronus does make dementors vanish

Answer (score 4):

There's plenty of speculation - though no definitive evidence (that I've seen - if there is, I'd *love* to see it) - that Dementors would fade away if removed permanently from the conditions in which they thrive and reproduce.

A Patronus is known to repel Dementors, so the most I think we could definitively say is that the Dementors would be trapped for as long as the sphere was intact.

Comment: Say "Sphere".. not circle.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Good point - I was thinking in two-dimensions.

Comment: But what is to "fade away"?

Answer (score 2):

According to JK Rowling herself, you cannot kill a Demontor. You can only reduce their speed of reproduction, by taking away the very thing that they thrive upon, fear misery and despair.

As already stated above, they would just be held there, imprisoned. They feed off a patronus, instead of the caster.

Comment: Was this supposed to be a comment?

Comment: Indeed it was, my bad! :)

Comment: It is only by ignorance of the wizards that they cannot destroy dementors.